# Is there any way to invoke the Erlang switch command on the CMD on Windows?

Tags: erlang, erl

When I invoke `erl` on the **CMD** I get this output:

```
Eshell V10.1  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

As far as I know, the switch command should kick in when I press **Ctrl + G**, but instead what I get is a new shell.

Do I have to press a different key combination? Does the switch command exist on `erl` for **Windows**?

Answer (score 0):

Because of how the CMD console works in Windows, the standard `erl` command is not suitable for running interactively. On Windows, you should use `werl` instead (which is what the installed icon runs) to get an interactive Erlang window. Then, Ctrl-G will enter Job Control Mode as expected.

Note also that the normal Ctrl-C for the Break menu does not work on Windows (since it's used for Copy/Paste) - instead you have to press the actual Break key. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key#Keyboards_without_Break_key if you can't find Break on your keyboard (`Fn-b` worked on my laptop).